# Conditional colors of labels in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I'm trying to map quintiles of a numeric variable across districts in a French region.
I managed to define my own color palette to fill the different districts according to the value of their respective quintile.
Now, I would like my labels to show the real value of the numeric variable (neuf_col). But, I would like the labels to be white if the quintiles are equal to 1 or 2, or black if the quintiles are equal to 3,4, or 5.

I coded the following, but when I mutate my data, ggplot does not recognize that it's a vector of color, and my labels appear blue and rose.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks!!

Sarah

```
cols <- c("#cfdeff", "#a0bfff", "#1f8a9d", "#0e4f55", "#0e4f55" )

#Define my quintile of my numeric variable
jointure$quantile_neuf_col<-cut(jointure$neuf_col,
                                breaks=c(quantile(jointure$neuf_col, probs = seq(0,1, by=0.2))),
                                include.lowest=TRUE,labels=FALSE)


 #Create a new column in my sfdata frame containing the color I want for my labels   
jointure <- mutate(jointure,
                   fill_col = case_when(
                     quantile_neuf_col == 1   ~ "white",
                     quantile_neuf_col == 2   ~ "white",
                     quantile_neuf_col  == 3  ~ "black",
                     quantile_neuf_col  == 4  ~ "black",
                     quantile_neuf_col  == 5  ~ "black"))

#ggplot 
ggplot(data = jointure, aes(fill = factor(quantile_neuf_col), 
                            label = neuf_col))  +   geom_sf()  + scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(color=fill_col), label.size=NA) +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.text=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        panel.background =element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        legend.position="none")[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjOFp.png)
```

Comment: Option 1: Try with `+ scale_color_identity()`. Option 2: `geom_sf_label(aes(color= quantile_neuf_col %in% 1:2), label.size=NA) + scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "white", "FALSE" = "black"))`